# Mousewheel will only zoom out

Tags: jquery, mousewheel

I have a bug using the [jquery.mousewheel plugin](http://brandonaaron.net/code/mousewheel/docs) where it will not recognize when I spin the wheel up.  For example I try this :

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#header')
        .bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta) {
           var dir = delta > 0 ? 'Up' : 'Down';
           console.log (dir);
           return false;
        });
});
```

I only get Down no matter which way I spin the wheel.  What could be causing this bug?  Anyone else encountered this? Any ideas where I could start looking or other code I could paste in to help debug.

I am using jQuery 1.7.1

Comment: Try printing the value of `delta` to the console.

Comment: yes i tried that it is always 0

Comment: are you using the most know mousewheel plugin? can you make a test in the jsfield?

Comment: Recent versions of the mousewheel plugin supply four parameters to your function: `(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY)`.  Do the extra two parameters contain anything useful?  Plus, what browser are you using?  Have you tried another?

Comment: Mousewheel Version: 3.0.3-pre, I am not sure how you make a test in jsfield...

Comment: I have tried in ff and chrome with same problem.  I am not sure what to do with those other parameters.. I just get undefined.

Comment: The changelog for mousewheel says "# 3.0.6 Fix issue with delta being 0 in Firefox".  Maybe try a later version.

Comment: Ahh that is it! I thought I had the latest version.  Also weird because it used to work and I tried to revert to the older version before but that didnt fix.  Thanks so much for your help.  You should add as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The changelog for mousewheel says "# 3.0.6 Fix issue with delta being 0 in Firefox".  Try the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

It works just fine in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/hoganlong/tGbnp/